# How do I break a text string down to two letter chunks, and convert those chunks to four digit numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to make a simple program for my number theory class. We're learning encryption.

The main encryption I want to demonstrate is demonstrated in this example:

Take the phrase "TAKE CARE"

as

TA
KE
-C
AR
E-

where TA is converted to 2001, because T is the 20th letter in the alphabet and A is the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you seem to be limiting yourself to ASCII, then you should be fine using the `-UTF8String` of the string:

```
NSString *source = @"TAKE CARE";
source = [source lowercaseString]; //normalize the capitalization
const char *characters = [source UTF8String];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [source length]; ++i) {
  const char character = characters[i];
  if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
    int positionInAlphabet = character - 'a' + 1; // this means "a" is "1"
    NSLog(@"%c = %d", character, positionInAlphabet);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"non-letter: %c", character);
  }
}
```

Comment: questions: 1) i have a text box for entering in the string of text, and want to pull that into the NSString *source. i've only ever seen NSString with a written string, is there another type of string for pulling things in from the window? 2) where does NSLog print to? i want to have a four digit string of numbers put into an integer, not just printed out, so that i can do math with them.

Comment: I figured it out...1) I replaced @"Take Care" with [messsage stringValue] and 2) it prints to the console window, but in order to actually place text in a field I need to call [answerField setStringValue]